# Payment method data not showing on Update order status emails

Tags: magento-1.9, email, payment-methods

Payment method title not showing on update order status emails like Status Update to **Preparing** and Status Update to **Shipping** emails. Its showing the block but not showing title.
Invoice and Shipment email are showing payment method data. 
Which file contains the payment block for update status emails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Still not sure on why payment data not showing on email but i fixed it to make it work in a different way.
In email template i updated `{{var payment_html}}` to `{{block type='core/template' area='frontend' template='email/order/pm.phtml' order=$order}}`.
Created new file pm.phtml in email/order folder:

```
<?php 
      $_order = $this->getOrder(); 
     if($_order) {
      $storeId = $_order->getStore()->getId();
      if($_order->getPayment()->getMethodInstance()->getCode() == 'cashondelivery') 
      {
          echo 'Some Text Message';      
      } else {
          $paymentBlock = Mage::helper('payment')->getInfoBlock($_order->getPayment())
                ->setIsSecureMode(true);
          $paymentBlock->getMethod()->setStore($storeId);
          $paymentBlockHtml = $paymentBlock->toHtml();
          echo $paymentBlockHtml;
      }
     }
?>
```